# How to add a button to remove user

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

I currently have this code that displays users on a team and when you click on the name of a user that is on the list it passes the name that you click to a function which removes them from the team. Instead I would like a button to be next to the name and when you click the button it removes the person that the button is next to. How would I go about doing this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#your_teams234").change(function() {

            var team = $("#your_teams234").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'functions.php',
                method: 'post',
                data: 'members=' + team
            }).done(function(requests) {
                console.log(requests);
                requests = JSON.parse(requests);
                $('#teammates').empty();
                if (requests.length != 0) {
                    $("#teamContainer").css("display", "block");
                    requests.forEach(function(request) {
                        $('#teammates').append('<p class="myDivs">' + request.email + '</p>')
                    })
                }
                if (requests.length == 0) {
                    $('#teammates').append(`<p> No teammates </p>`)
                }
                $('.myDivs').click(function() {
                    $var1 = $(this).text();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'functions.php',
                        type: 'post',
                        data: {
                            "callFunc1": $var1,
                            "teamName": team
                        },
                        success: function(response) {
                            console.log(response);
                        }
                    });
                });
            })
        })
    })
```

Here is the html code for my team container

```
<div id="teamContainer" style="display: none;">
    <p style="font-weight: bold; font-size:18px left">Current Team Members (click name to remove)</p>
    <div id='teammates'>
    </div>
    <hr style="margin-left: 350px; margin-right: 350px">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Is the question about HTML layout? Please show some HTML in any case.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you really should be passing ID's rather than names in order to access a user. What if you have 2 users with the same name, or apostrophes/odd characters - or even the lack of a name? At any rate, you didn't show your HTML but here's how it could work.

```js
$('.remover').click(function() {
  let $user = $(this).closest('.user-container').find('.myDivs');
  let $userid = $user.data('id');
  let $username = $user.text();
  console.log(`remove user ${$username}, id ${$userid}`);
  $(this).closest('.user-container').remove()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='user-container'>
  <span class='myDivs' data-id='1'>John Smith</span>
  <button class='remover'>Remove user</button>
</div>

<div class='user-container'>
  <span class='myDivs' data-id='2'>Susan Sarandon</span>
  <button class='remover'>Remove user</button>
</div>

<div class='user-container'>
  <span class='myDivs' data-id='3'>Bill Nye</span>
  <button class='remover'>Remove user</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I added the html code for clarification sorry for omitting it